# How to add digits like 00,01.. in drop down list in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drop-down-menu

I need to add a drop down for selecting the minutes.I have tried through component parameters in FLA and through XML.When i gave the value 00,01..etc they are taken as 0,1.But i need 00,01..etc.
 How it is possible.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume that they're being treated as `Number`s, my advice would be:

```
var numAsString:String = myNumber.toString();
if (numAsString.length<2) {numAsString = "0"+numAsString;}
```

That should force it to show in the format you want. Just be sure to use `parseInt(numAsString)` if you need to do any manipulation.